# Usage of GHashTable from GLib?

Tags: c, glib

I am trying to use a [`GHashTable`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) in my code. I will be using an `int` as my key and a structure as my value. My questions:

- Will I have to allocate memory for the `int` I am using as a key, or can I just use a local variable in the functions for insert and lookup?
- What does `g_int_to_pointer` do?
- If I am writing a `GDestroyFunction`, will I have to free any memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will I have to allocate memory for the int I am using as a key, or can I just use a local variable in the functions for insert and lookup?

No you can pass the integer by value, you do not need to allocate it on the heap with `malloc()` or the like.

> What does g_int_to_pointer do?

Sorry, I don't know that one.

> If I am writing a GDestroyFunction, will I have to free any memory?

Did you mean [GDestroyNotify](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Datasets.html#GDestroyNotify)? As the documentation states:

> Specifies the type of function which is called when a data element is destroyed. It is passed the pointer to the data element and should free any memory and resources allocated for it.

Yes, you do have to free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

`GINT_TO_POINTER` (mind the capital letters) packs a 32-bit `int` into the space of a pointer, which may be 32 or 64-bit. You can use this macro to pass `int`s as the `user_data` parameter of a signal, while avoiding allocating memory for them, for example. Then in the signal handler, use `GPOINTER_TO_INT` to get your int back. Don't try to dereference the pointer!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was thinking of using a int as a `key` while using a `GHashTable`. I can use `G_INT_TO_POINTER` to convert this to a pointer so that it can be used in [link] (http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-insert). At the time of retrieval from the table, can i use the same `G_INT_TO_POINTER` macro to convert the int to the pointer required? Will they both be guaranteed to be the same reference?

Comment: No you need to use `GPOINTER_TO_INT` to get the original int back as stated in the answer. BTW, I tried to fix the the typo (you do not need '_' after G)in the answer but SO complained to that my edit is too short.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typos. I think you misunderstood the OP's followup question, but I'm not sure now - because I forget how I interpreted it when I answered "yes" last year...

Comment: @yasushi My question was not how get back the int from the pointer, but whether I could use the G_INT_TO_POINTER to get back a key to use in g_hash_table_lookup. And the answer is yes